# Missing driver source code in Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, c, source-code, beagleboard

I'm trying to create an spi Linux module. When I try to see function definition of built-in functions in the path referred in [Bootlin Elixir Cross Referencer](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.9/source/drivers/spi) in my system, I'm unable to find the C source code file.

Can somebody tell me how to find the C source files in Ubuntu?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the source file is not included on your system because it's already compiled from the source.

Comment: "The C source" of what?

Comment: Kernel module C source file that should have been present in drivers/spi directory

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of all built-in kernel modules, run the following command.

```
cat /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.builtin
```

To get a list of all built-in kernel modules containing the string `spi`, run the following command.

```
cat /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.builtin | grep spi
```

You should expect to see some positive results from the second command showing that built-in spi kernel module(s) are installed on your system. Searching for files that end in `spi.ko` in Ubuntu 18.04 gives the following [results](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&section=all&arch=any&keywords=spi.ko&searchon=contents), many of which are drivers, for example ethernet and touchscreen.

There are also many spi.ko files in `/lib/modules/`. You can use `dpkg -S <path>` to find out what package installed the selected spi.ko file. For example:

```
dpkg -S '/lib/modules/4.15.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/iio/common/st_sensors/st_sensors_spi.ko'
```

I don't type the path, instead I drag the file's icon from the file manager into the terminal and the path prints after the cursor position automatically. Results:

```
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-45-generic: /lib/modules/4.15.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/iio/common/st_sensors/st_sensors_spi.ko
```

To download the source code of a package that contains a driver run the following command:

```
apt --download-only source <package_name>
```

Comment: I don't think you understood my question. What i want to find are the C files as mentioned in the above link rather than the .ko files.

Comment: The Linux kernel is a monolithic Unix-like computer operating system kernel. The basic Linux Kernel is written in C and the Assembly language. Virtually all of the Linux kernel (the source of which you can find at torvalds/linux) is written in C. There are small bits of code here and there that are written in assembly language, which you can find in that source tree by looking for files whose names end in .S instead of .c. Most of these bits deal with manipulating the state of the processor in ways that the C language simply has no way to specify.